# Geographic map overview of work assignments

Tags: web-apps, web-services, google-maps

I have been looking around for a tool which satisfies the following requirements or partly satisfies:

1. Be able to create work assignments on specific locations by typing
   the address or clicking a map (for example google maps)
2. Be able to add meta data to work assignments such as description etc.
3. Be able to COLOR work assignments according to for example priority.
4. The data should be persisted and secured with login.
5. Be able to display the   map (google map) on a preferred media (BIG
   Smart-TV in this case)which shows all created and active work
   assignments.

The question is if it already exists as either freeware or conventional buy to use. ???

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you also want to assign work to people/ And, when they finish something, assign them something else automatically?

Comment: @Mawg No that is not necessary. The whole idea is to have an overview of all active tasks presented on a country map, for example on a big screen and being able to manage these tasks (create, edit, delete) these tasks. One simple solution would be a web-interface to create,edit,delete etc, some integration to google Maps and using a big screen TV to present the tasks (using their location) on a MAP of the country. I could make it, but i would assume there is already something available out there ? :)

Comment: Personally, I would check on SourceForge & GitHub before starting, but, you know users - once you show them something, they are going to want to add features. You might be better to develop it yourself, then sit back & wait for feature creep

Comment: @Mawg You are right. But i have previously had good ideas. Searched the WEB for existing apps but not found any and then implemented it myself. Only to later discover, that there was something out there. I was only using the wrong search words when looking for it, or i could have saved a lot of time using already implemented wrapper classes which would have made my interfaces to third-party easier. Thanks for the responses anyways Mawg ..

Comment: I you do code something & FOSS it, please come back & leave a link here. It sounds like a fun & Interesting project.